# What's the general term for something to which things can be assigned?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

So I'm writing a Rails app where you can assign tasks to either people or teams, using polymorphism. However, I need to give the polymorphic interface a name — I was originally going to use *assignable*, but then I realized that something that's assignable can be assigned, as opposed to something to which tasks can be assigned.

Here's an example sentence:

> A task can be assigned to anything that is ____ (i.e a person or team).

It should be synonymous with "capable of being assigned/performing tasks".

Note: While I'd prefer a single word, a short phrase (one to two words, ideally no more than 20 characters including spaces) would do as well.

Comment: anything that implements TaskPerformer ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider **taskable**.  From *The Sapphire Affair: The True Story Behind Alfred Hitchcock's Topaz* by Fergus Mason:

> Intelligence officers draw a clear line between sources who can be
>   given instructions – they're called “**taskable**” sources – and those
>   who aren't. Anyone can potentially give valuable information, but a
>   **taskable** source can be told what to look for then sent out to report if they see it or  not.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the word you are looking for is *processor*.

The second of processor is:
"a person or thing that carries out a process".

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be possible to say that ***tasks will be given to assignees***?

Whilst ***assignee*** is clearly the answer to your title question, i.e. *what's the general term for something to which things can be assigned?*, it does not seem to fit the blank in your sample sentence.

But I do think it's the word you are looking for.

Comment: It doesn't fit the blank because as far as I can tell, the Rails standard for polymorphic names is to use an adjective. I'm admittedly not certain about that, though.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes But you said, in the last sentence of your OP, you needed *something to which tasks could be assigned*. If you are looking for a *something*, then it must be a noun. I don't see how a *something* can be an adjective!

Comment: I need [a Rails-style name for] something to which tasks could be assigned. I thought that was implied.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes You need to be on a different Stack Exchange site e.g. Computer Science, or Programming. This one is about the English language! I don't know anything about *Rails*, but I do, to some extent anyway, speak the Queen's English.

Comment: I'm looking for an English word, which (*as I said in my question*) "should be synonymous with 'capable of being assigned/performing tasks'." That's an adjective. I think you should be on another site, too, where reading the question isn't necessary, and you can cherry-pick phrases to support your bad answer as being valid. Also, please read my first comment on your answer. If you'll notice, it says precisely what the Rails standard is.